# Safari won't play audio from javascript

Tags: jquery, safari, audio-player

I'm having a problem that Safari on the Mac won't play audio on a button click.  I know auto-play is disabled, but this is based on user action so I'm really confused.  Plays fine in other browsers.

In my webpage I use jquery to dynamically build up the page and I'm adding a button which will play audio like so:

```javascript
var button = $('<button>', {
    id:      id + '_button',
    hidden:  'hidden',
    onclick: "preview('" + id + "')"
}).append($('<img>', {
    src: 'pb.gif',
    alt: 'Preview'
}));
```

And then in the `preview` method I play the sound.

```javascript
function preview(rowId) {
    var url = 'ajax/preview.php?t=' + ... + '.mp3';  // Long URL build up here

    var snd = new Audio();
    snd.src = url;
    snd.play();
}
```

The strange thing is that for me the sound plays just fine in Safari when I click the button, but basically everyone else I've had try this says there's no sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the server was sending back the header as `Content-Type: $contentType` instead of expanding that variable.  Once I fixed that it started working.

Comment: How did you fix it? Any hope that I can know it in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is related to iPhones, then I would suggest to check mute button on top left edge of the phone once.

Comment: No, this is on a mac.